# Resize Container based on UITableView Size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView embedded in a Container view, however, I want to have that update and resize based on the size of the UITableView. I have tried to use preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer() but it doesn't look like a Container View is a UIContentContainer? I'm not really sure how to trigger this so that my UITableView is not cut off, as I don't want it to scroll I was it to look all static. Here is a picture of what I have here.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I could do, or is there an observer I could use?

Comment: I think this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22524085/3228888

Comment: You might want to use a UIStackView instead. It was added to do make this easy.

Comment: I tried those both, and they didn't seem to work the way I need things set up. But for some reason the container view keeps saying it's nil, when it's connected to my code. Any idea why?