# Dequeing reusable Cell crash in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm having some troubles adding new cells on table view.

The strange thing is that I run once the function works perfectly without problems, if I do it for a second time it crash with this error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Here my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if prodottoDaAggiungere != nil {
        prodotti.append(prodottoDaAggiungere!)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: prodotti.count-1, section: 1)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) // ?
        prodottoDaAggiungere = nil
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < prodotti.count && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProdottoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProdottoTableViewCell // Crash :|
        let indexRow = indexPath.row // Fix
        cell.title.text = "\(prodotti[indexRow].prodotto.nome!) - \(prodotti[indexRow].prodotto.marca!)"
        cell.subtitle.text = "\(prodotti[indexRow].prodotto.formati[prodotti[indexRow].formato].dimensione) \(prodotti[indexRow].prodotto.unitàMisura!) - \(prodotti[indexRow].prodotto.formati[prodotti[indexRow].formato].prezzo) €"
        cell.number.text = Int(cell.stepper.value).description // 1
        cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        return cell
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Using breakpoint I founded app crash on the dequeueReusableCell but I cannot understand why, someone could tell me why this code crash?

Here my tableView numberOfRowsInSection func:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else if section == 1 {
        return 1+prodotti.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Cell]

[image: Result]

Really thanks
AP

Comment: can you share the prodotti array initialization?

Comment: try set indexPath row to `prodotti.count -1`

Comment: @Mac3n It crash again with the same error but now I can use use the function 2 times, crash the third.

Comment: Could you please post the numberOfRowsInSection function ?

Comment: @HarishSaran db.collection("Prodotti").whereField("Categoria", isEqualTo: category)
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        self.prodotti.append(Prodotto(id: document.documentID, data: document.data()))
                    }
                }
        }

Comment: @πter added in question :)

Comment: Never, never ever call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`. It's completely pointless – the cell is created and thrown away at the end of the method – as well as `beginUpdates/endUpdates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49157374/8737121

Really thanks to:
[Shan Ye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5867574/shan-ye)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this part:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: prodotti.count, section: 1)
```

If `prodotti.count` is 2 then you are trying to scroll to the row with index 2, when the count is 2. You need to switch it so that you are going to `count - 1`, like this:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: prodotti.count - 1, section: 1)
```

Additionally, you will need to update the array `prodotti` with new item you added. Since your number of rows in that section is `prodotti` + 2, it is working the first two times, but since you haven't actually increased the size of `prodotti`, the tableview doesn't know that there should now be more rows.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer, I tried to modify the question by simplifying it but adding important data, maybe I can make you understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have bounds from index `0` to `N - 1`, being `N = yourArray.count`.
So your upper bound should get to `yourArray.count - 1`. In your case:

`let indexPath = IndexPath(row: prodotti.count - 1, section: 0)`

Note that the sections also start with `0`.

In other words: The number of elements is different from their actual indexes, which are their current position minus 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer, I tried to modify the question by simplifying it but adding important data, maybe I can make you understand better.

Comment: So this is why is not section 0, but one.