# Static and dynamic cells in one UITableviewcontroller using Storyboards

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard

I want a table view like this [image]

What i understood is that they are using static cells other than where to display call details.How to make a tableview like the above one(where dynamic cells are kept  between static cells).I went through lot of stuff like this [How to implement UITableView With Static and Dynamic Cells -- IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679745/how-to-implement-uitableview-with-static-and-dynamic-cells-ios),[this was the best of all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322885/combine-static-and-prototype-content-in-a-table-view),but was not able to find a solution.Any tutorials or advice would be appreciated.I'm still in pursuit of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is difficult to do.

1. First, using custom UITableViewCell which has method [YourCustomCell heightForItem:(object)yourItem].
2. Using `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to return the height of cell for each row. Example in my code:

   `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       MyAddress *address = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
       return [MyAddressCell cellHeightForAddress:address];
   }`
3. Inside `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, fill the data into your cell:

   `MyAddress *address = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
   [cell fillWithAddress:address];`

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a couple of approaches:

## 1

The easier way is to create a different `UITableViewController` for every possible combination of static and dynamic table view cells there may ever be in your app. This means that the Contacts app above will have one `UITableViewController` when there are no call logs for the user being displayed, and another one when there already are. There are downsides to this approach: a) If you are in the table view controller with call logs and the logs are cleared, switching to the log-less one may be difficult; b) If you're using storyboards, copy-pasting a prototype cell across many view controllers can also be difficult. I'm sure there are more, but for some screens with simple functionality (ones that aren't forms), the ease of building it this way outweighs the disadvantages.

## 2

Consider your screen as a static `UITableView` with dynamically resizing `UIView`s inside. For example, the above contacts app will be a table view with 4 rows: the mugshot AND call logs, the home number, Facetime, and Notes. The mugshot and call logs are in a single custom `UIView` in a single `UITableViewCell`. If there are no call logs for the user being displayed, the custom `UIView` only displays the mugshot, but if there are, it also displays the call logs.

In short, the `numberOfRowsInSection:` is constant--the `UIView`s inside the `UITableViewCell`s are not. If a row dynamically appears or disappears, put it in the same row as the one above it, **just make sure to compute for the cell's height in** `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` depending on whether the dynamic component should be shown or not.